# TCP handshake latency

Tags: networking, tcp, latency

I have 2 machines on a 100 Gb/s LAN which talk to each other over TCP.
When I do a tracert or a ping from the client to the server, even a large ping, I get an answer in less then **1 ms**.
However, when I'm sniffing the TCP packets on the client side, I see that **40ms** pass between the time it sends the first message of the 3-way handshake, to the time it receives the answer from the server.
The server is dedicated to this client and handles nothing else.

Is this reasonable? I'd expect it to be much much faster.

Comment: This should be on serverfault.

Comment: ping is ICMP-> layer 3.  
TCP is layer 4.
Not sure about timing though. It should be much closer.. i.e. 5ms in this case.

Comment: client is on a Windows Server, server is on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting TCP_NODELAY and combining a couple of messages to a single one did the trick, messages were just too small.